# Android - How to auto size TextView to fit within a fixed height container?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

Basically I want my TextView to autosize only relative tho the fixed height of the TextView container and NOT to the length of the text. Is this achievable in XML only (no Kotlin)?

Current implementation:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            style="@style/TextSFontMd"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@{text}"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="@dimen/_1ssp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            tools:maxLength="10"
            tools:text="@string/placeholder_lorem_ipsum_short" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work for you

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                style="@style/TextSFontMd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@{text}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                tools:maxLength="10"
                tools:text="@string/placeholder_lorem_ipsum_short" />
```

Comment: I thought about this, but is there any chance that the height will be scaled weirdly on some stupid device and the text will appear cut?

Comment: I think it will work because you are using SDP and SSP for size and this both library use for auto-size

Comment: All right, thanks, I will keep that 4sdp difference between the text size and view height just in case.